# I am trying to debug this code it is giving me a NameError: name'male_count' is not defined. Here is what I have so far

Tags: debugging

#allow user to enter data for multiple individuals
name = raw_input("what is your name?: ")

age = raw_input("what is age?: ")

sex = raw_input("Please enter male or female: ")

while name != "":

```
if sex == "male":

    male_count = male_count + 1
```

male_age = male_age + int(age)

if sex == "female":

```
female_count = female_count + 1
```

female_age = female_age + int(age)

print("Please enter male or female")

#calculate average age for males and females

if male_count > 0:

```
male_avg = male_age / male_count
```

if female_count > 0:

```
female_avg = female_age / female_count
```

print("There are",male_count,"males with an average age of",male_avg)

print("There are",female_count,"females with an average age of",female_avg)

Answer (score 0):

You never declare `male_count = 0`